# Allow ctrl+click navigation on method parameters in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I want to write a helper function in asp.net MVC to embed js and css files by adding some stuff in the url. Something like...

```
public static IHtmlString AddJavascript<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, string jsFilePath) { ... }
```

So instead of

```
<script src="~/Scripts/menu-functions.js?v=@ApplicationHelper.VersionId"></script>
```

I would use

```
@Html.AddJavascript("~/Scripts/menu-functions.js")
```

However in the first case if I do CTRL+Click on the file path Visual Studio opens it.

Is there a way to make the parameter navigable in the helper method too?